# How to display individual records in view (when stored in variable that uses lambda in controller)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller I have a var that contains records from my database. My problem is, that I need to display individual records in my view, but nothing has worked so far.

I've tried using

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault()
```

but that sometimes return a null value.

This is from my controller:

```
// GET: hold/protokol
public ActionResult Protokol(int? id)
{
var kursus_kursist = db.kursus_kursist.Where(x => x.kursus_id == id).Include(k => k.kurser).Include(k => k.kursister);

return View(kursus_kursist.ToList());
}
```

In k.kurser there is a column named startdato which contains dates and a kursus_id (the primary key). What I want is to be able to show the value of the startdato column where kursus_id matches id from public ActionResult Protokol(int? id) in my view. *edit: The result should be a headline with the date, so I only need to show this value once. I'm really just going for an output like this:
"2019-11-04"
* I'm guessing I can access it somehow using razor in the view, but how?

I'm (obviously) having a hard time grasping this, and so I find it difficult to put my problem into word. Please let me know if I need to update/edit my question.
Thanks

Comment: Share your entity class structure and expected output

Comment: @shyju, by entity class structure, do you mean the controller.cs file contents?

Comment: `@Model.FirstOrDefault()` only returns first record. Use `for` or `foreach` loop to iterate the model contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the existing controller you would have the reference the collection of models and then use a foreach within razor like so:

```
   @model List<kursis_kursist>


    @foreach (kursis_kursist item in Model)
    {
     //Access individual items here
    }
```

Edit:

You could create a ViewModel containing the DateTime value for the header and the collection like so:

```
public class KursistViewModel
{
 public DateTime HeaderDate {get; set;}
 public List<kursis_kursist> kursisList {get; set;}
}
```

You can then pass this to the view and access the HeaderDate directly with Razor and access the List via a foreach.

Comment: But wouldn't that print out multiple items (with the same value)? I need to make a headline that contains the date, so I only need to print the date once.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hopefully this is what you are after